# How can i easily find other computer connected with a ethernet cable on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, crossover-cable

I have two PC's with Windows 7 that connect to internet via WiFi. But when i want to transfer large amount of  data between them, i connect both with a network cable.

When i do this, Windows assigns a crazy IP to each, and i can reach PC1 by typing PC2's ip on explorer, for instance: `\\169.254.175.51`

To find PC1's ip I open a `cmd` and type `ipconfig /all`, and locate the ip for the ethernet adapter. Then i have to mind this number and go to PC2 and type it.

This works very well but it's quite bothersome. I could assign a fixed ip to PC2, but then i would have to change this every time i have to connect it to a cabled network. I don't know if naming the computer would work, but i'm afraid the wireless connection would be used instead of the cabled.

So, is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: So long as you disable the wifi adapter when the cable is in use the name resolution should be fine - provided you have network discovery settings set - and you're assured of using the LAN instead of WiFi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a static IP address to the network cards (10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2).  Then put them in the same subnet (subnetmask 255.255.255.251).  That should about do it.

NOTE: This assumes you aren't using a 10.0.0.0 network for your WiFi connections.

For more info (and pretty pictures) go [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/).

Just so you know, those crazy IP addresses are referred to as self assigned.

Comment: the problem with this is that sometimes i go to a place where there's only cabled internet available. so i would have to set the adapter to dhcp again, and then back when i want to crossover.

Comment: If you want to be DHCP compatible with this other destination, you need to buy a router that has DHCP capability and put it between the two computers, then hook both computers to it.

Comment: I assume that this answers the question?

Comment: no, it's even ON the question itself "I could assign a fixed ip to PC2, but then i would have to change this every time i have to connect it to a cabled network."

Comment: Then there is no answer for you.